# libzip makefile error: make: *** No rule to make target `/Makefile.common'. Stop

Tags: makefile, zip

I cloned libzip from github and now want to do the make but it gives an error ***No rule to make target '/Makefile.common' Stop. The cloned folder (libzip) has 3 files (libzip.spec, sources, Makefile).This is the Makefile, what could be the problem.

```
# This makefile is downloading any file found in 
# the 'sources' file already existing in this directory
# and validating the sha256sum of the archive against it.
NAME := libzip

define find-common-dir
for d in common ../common ../../common ; do if [ -f $$d/Makefile.common ] ; then echo "$$d"; break ; fi ; done
endef
COMMON_DIR := $(shell $(find-common-dir))

include $(COMMON_DIR)/Makefile.common

SOURCEFILES := $(shell cat sources 2>/dev/null | awk '{ print $$2 }' | awk -F'*' '{ print $$2 }')

sources: $(SOURCEFILES)

$(SOURCEFILES):
    @for sourcefile in $(SOURCEFILES); do \
        $(CLIENT) $(LOOKASIDE_URI)/$(NAME)/$${sourcefile}; \
    done

    sha256sum -c sources || ( echo 'SHA256 check failed' && rm $(SOURCEFILES); exit 1 )

clean:
    rm $(SOURCEFILES)
```

Comment: This makefile is looking for `Makefile.common` (in `.`, `../common/` and `../../common/`) and not finding it. It has no rule to build `Makefile.common`, it just expects to find it somewhere.

Comment: What is the link to the libzip you cloned? I tried this one: https://github.com/JanX2/libzip-git, but it looks different from what you describe, and it works fine.

Answer (score -1):

Please use the official mercurial repository:
http://hg.nih.at/libzip/
and let us know if you still have problems.